# Prevent deadlock in Resource Allocation

Tags: resources, deadlock

Consider a simple problem where we have 2 (say **A** and **B**) resources and 2 customers (say **1** and **2**). Suppose we have initially allocated **A** to **1** and **B** to **2**. Now suppose we want to switch the allocation synchronously. Clearly for a general algorithm with no prior knowledge A and B both will appear busy as they are being used by **1** & **2**.

So clearly there is a deadlock even though a swithc should be possible. Now generalize this problem to **R** resources and **U** users. Is there any efficient algorithm to check whether or not the allocation is actually possible vs when there is a deadlock as above.